# node js TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addListener'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a project to detect incoming messages on a irc chat, and if a message says right left up or down, it will simulate a key press on the corresponding right left up or down key, making it so I can connect to the twich irc and live stream a 2048 board, so the viewers play the game from chat. I am using node.js with the libraries "irc" and "kbm-robot". The irc library and the kbm-robot library worked perfectly when they where apart but when I put both library files in the "node_modules" folder and combined the code, the irc library stopped working. When ever I try to execute the code I get the error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'addListener'". Here's the code I have written so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var irc = require('./irc/lib/irc.js');

var client = new irc.Client('irc.twitch.tv', 'themakat', {
    channels: ["#themakat"],
    nick: "themakat",
    password: "oauth:(passkey)",
    sasl: true
});

var kbmrobot = require("kbm-robot");

function right() {
    kbmrobot.startJar();

    kbmrobot.press("right")
    .sleep(100)
    .release("right")
    .go()
    .then(kbmrobot.stopJar);
};

function left() {
    kbmrobot.startJar();

    kbmrobot.press("left")
    .sleep(100)
    .release("left")
    .go()
    .then(kbmrobot.stopJar);
};

function up() {
    kbmrobot.startJar();

    kbmrobot.press("up")
    .sleep(100)
    .release("up")
    .go()
    .then(kbmrobot.stopJar);
};

function down() {
    kbmrobot.startJar();

    kbmrobot.press("down")
    .sleep(100)
    .release("down")
    .go()
    .then(kbmrobot.stopJar);
};

up();

irc.addListener('message#themakat', function(from, message) {
    console.log('<%s> %s', from, message);
    if ('right' == message) {
        right();
        console.log('right');
}   else if ('left' == message) {
        left();
        console.log('left');
}   else if ('up' == message) {
        up();
        console.log('up');
}   else if ('down' == message) {
        down();
        console.log('down');
};
});
```

Because I am just 13, I have probably made some dumb mistakes on explaining my situation. If I have made any mistakes with explanation please correct me so I know for future reference. Thank you so much!

Comment: Wait, you just "put" the libraries in node_modules? Not like npm installed them?

Comment: Tip: you can use `.on()` instead of `.addListener()` to make it more succinct. Also, you should typically use npm to install packages instead of copying files around manually.

Comment: To clarify, I did npm install them... sorry I mistyped that

Comment: Note: you can load module like `var irc = require('irc');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want your client to be listening instead of the irc module.

```
client.addlistener()
```

or more recommended (because it's clearer/cleaner)

```
client.on()
```

You can handle errors as well by adding an error handler.

```
client.on('error', function(err) { 
    console.log(err); 
});
```

Comment: I have changed irc to client (Thank you!), but now I am getting this error message:

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:558:19)

Comment: Does that happen immediately?

Comment: If you are sure everything was working earlier, you might want to try adding an error handler to see if it will catch the error. `client.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });`

Comment: Ok, so I added client.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err); }); at the top (after the #!/usr/bin/env node) and the bottom, and both times I got the same error... I tried also to replace client.on with client.addListener. Here's the error message:

Comment: /root/Desktop/2048 irc/node_modules/bot.js:3
client.addListener('error', function(err) { console.log(err); });
       ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'addListener' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/Desktop/2048 irc/node_modules/bot.js:3:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Comment: You need to do it after you initialized the client. Just like the other one. So you can place it at the bottom.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I removed the one at the top and I got this:

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:558:19)

Comment: Oh wait! never mind! I FIXED IT!!! Thank you so much!! couldn't have done it with out you!

Comment: I have updated the answer, up vote or accept the answer if it worked for you. :)

Comment: I am sorry! I joined stack overflow to ask this question, and I can't up vote with less then 15 rep... But I would up vote 30 times over if I could.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `irc.addListener(` to `client.addListener(`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, so it half worked. So it solved the "has not method 'hasListener'" problem... but now it is giving me the error message 

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:558:19)

Thank you so much for your help!